Decidability and Semi-Decidability of Languages Defined by Turing Machines
Let's define the input alphabet (A = {0, 1}) and the tape alphabet (T = {0, 1, B}).
Let (U) be a universal machine. For a word ($w \in A^*$), we define the Turing machine ($M_w$) as follows: if (w) is the code of some machine (M), then (M_w := M),
and otherwise (M_w := U).
For the following languages, determine if it is decidable and if it is
semi-decidable.
[L_1 = {$w \in A^* \mid M_w$ $\text{ is a machine with a number of states that is a power of two}$}]
My idea was first to check whether

encodes some machine
. This is decidable. Then to count the number of states of machine
 and check if it is a power of two. Checking whether a number is a power of two is decidable. Therefore,

is a decidable language. Does it make any sense or I should solve in another way?

The idea is good, but I think it would be better to describe decision procedure explicitly (check, if $w$ encodes some machine; if yes - check number of states and return yes/no; if no - you didn't write what to do). "Check some property, this is decidable" isn't very good expression - decidability is property of languages, not checks.

@mihaild Actually I have no idea, how to solve the problem if f w doesn't
encode any machine, can you give some propmts?

Well, assume that $w$ doesn't encode any machine. Which machine is then $M_w$? How many states does it have?

@mihaild It will be universal turing machine then, but I don't know how many states it has.

When you define "universal machine", you also define it's number of states.

@mihaild Do you mean that, if w will encode universal machine, I can define how many states this machine will have? For example, could I say that every universal machine will have 2^n of states, so I just  immediately say  it belongs to language?

No, I mean for the problem to be fully specified, $U$ should be some specific machine.

@mihaild But I don't know anything about this maching except of it's universal.

@mihaild Will there be another solution if the machine will be univeral? I don't understand how it differs in this task from any other turing machine.

It will be the same solution (but of course possibly different function).

@mihaild So, should I just write that in the case it will be universal machine the solution will be the same as for "normal" TM?
